# OSX Automator failing to run Python script with modules from shell

Tags: python, macos, shell, automator, twython

I am trying to run a Python script that uses a few 3rd party modules (numpy, pandas, Twython) from `Run Shell Script` in OSX Automator. I wrote a hello_world.py script that runs successfully so I'm certain that the problem is due to the 3rd party modules.

In Terminal, I can successfully execute: `python Desktop/my_folder/myscript.py`, however when I try to run the shell script below, the shell script fails. I run Python 2.7.7 from anaconda distribution.

```
#!/Users/myName/anaconda/bin/python2.7

cd ~/Desktop/my_folder/
python script.py
```

How do I write a shell script that works for Python scripts that use 3rd party modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the absolute path to the Anaconda Python when you invoke Python, not  as a shebang line (which apparently is ignored by Automator anyway).  When running a shell script under Automator, your shell startup profiles are probably not being run so the changes that put the Anaconda `bin` directory on `PATH` do not happen, causing `python` to refer to the system `Python`.  Try this instead.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/Desktop/my_folder/
/Users/myName/anaconda/bin/python2.7 script.py
```

Comment: For clarification on how this works, you change directories to `/Desktop/my_folder` and then run to `/Users/myName/anaconda/bin/python2.7 script.py`?

Comment: Wait, I figured it out. The `cd <path>/my_folder` takes to where your `my_script.py` is, and then `/Users/myName/anaconda/bin/python2.7` tells the computer to use Anaconda's version of python instead of the system's version of python to run `my_script.py`