# How to get Automator to recognize python script with pyperclip?

Tags: python, macos, shell, anaconda, automator

I'm using Automator in Mac OSX 10.12.3 to run a Python script utilizing [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip). I created an Automator step with Run Shell Script (`/usr/bin/python`):

```
import pyperclip
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
pyperclip.copy(str(now.year) + str(now.month) + str(now.day) + '_' + str(now.hour) + str(now.minute) + str(now.second))
```

However, it is showing this error:

```
ImportError: No module named pyperclip
```

I can execute this code in Terminal, why pyperclip is not recognized by `/usr/bin/python` ? FYI, I also have Anaconda installed.

Comment: Are you sure that the `pyperclip` is installed in your machine?

Comment: how did you install pyperclip? Did you download it and is it a subdirectory of your script?

Comment: I can see why: /usr/bin/python in Mac OSX is python 2.7 while I install pyperclip under Anaconda virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Automator is using `/usr/bin/python` while I installed pyperclip under Anaconda virtualenv. When I run python, I noticed it said :

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Look like it is a different python version compared to the one Automator is using. Now all I have to do is:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install pyperclip
```

Comment: I'm encountering a very similar error, but in automator I can only get it to run (and encounter the "No module named ..." error) using /bin/bash. Any idea how I can install my module (robobrowser) in /bin/bash? I attempted "sudo /bin/bash -m pip install robobrowser" but it errors out

Comment: are you using any virtualenv ? What is the output of `pip install robobrowse` ? Note you don't have to use `sudo bash` for pip

Comment: Yea, I'm using anaconda. I was able to figure it out though. I had to point my computer to anaconda's version of python as opposed to the system's version of python. Able to load all third party libraries. Used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24464135/9158985) to do it